Why does dmidecode return a higher number of banks than the number of memory channels supported by the CPU?
According to the wiki, a bank refers to the secondary structure of a DRAM chip, which is different from the bank mentioned in the dmidecode command. I am wondering what the relationship is between these two concepts and why they are using the same term?
Additionally, when I run the dmidecode command on a certain machine, I find that there are 32 banks on the machine, even though it should have only 16 memory channels (2 * Intel 8352Y CPU = 2 * 8channel). Why would there be more banks than channel number? What is the relationship between the memory bank in here and the memory channel?
Handle 0x0044, DMI type 17, 92 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0043
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 72 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 64 GB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: CPU0_DIMM_A0
    Bank Locator: NODE 0
    Type: DDR4
    Type Detail: Synchronous Registered (Buffered)
    Speed: 3200 MHz
    Manufacturer: Samsung
    Serial Number: 43F7C3DF
    Asset Tag: CPU0_DIMM_A0_AssetTag
    Part Number: M393A8G40BB4-CWE
    Rank: 2
    Configured Clock Speed: 3200 MHz
    Minimum Voltage: 1.2 V
    Maximum Voltage: 1.2 V
    Configured Voltage: 1.2 V

Handle 0x0045, DMI type 17, 92 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0043
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: Unknown
    Data Width: Unknown
    Size: No Module Installed
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: CPU0_DIMM_A1
    Bank Locator: NODE 0
    Type: Unknown
    Type Detail: Unknown
    Speed: Unknown
    Manufacturer: NO DIMM
    Serial Number: NO DIMM
    Asset Tag: NO DIMM
    Part Number: NO DIMM
    Rank: Unknown
    Configured Clock Speed: Unknown
    Minimum Voltage: Unknown
    Maximum Voltage: Unknown
    Configured Voltage: Unknown

Handle 0x0046, DMI type 17, 92 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0043
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 72 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 64 GB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: CPU0_DIMM_B0
    Bank Locator: NODE 0
    Type: DDR4
    Type Detail: Synchronous Registered (Buffered)
    Speed: 3200 MHz
    Manufacturer: Samsung
    Serial Number: 43F7C3DD
    Asset Tag: CPU0_DIMM_B0_AssetTag
    Part Number: M393A8G40BB4-CWE
    Rank: 2
    Configured Clock Speed: 3200 MHz
    Minimum Voltage: 1.2 V
    Maximum Voltage: 1.2 V
    Configured Voltage: 1.2 V

Handle 0x0047, DMI type 17, 92 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0043
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: Unknown
    Data Width: Unknown
    Size: No Module Installed
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: CPU0_DIMM_B1
    Bank Locator: NODE 0
    Type: Unknown
    Type Detail: Unknown
    Speed: Unknown
    Manufacturer: NO DIMM
    Serial Number: NO DIMM
    Asset Tag: NO DIMM
    Part Number: NO DIMM
    Rank: Unknown
    Configured Clock Speed: Unknown
    Minimum Voltage: Unknown
    Maximum Voltage: Unknown
    Configured Voltage: Unknown

Handle 0x0048, DMI type 17, 92 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0043
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 72 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 64 GB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: CPU0_DIMM_C0
    Bank Locator: NODE 1
    Type: DDR4
    Type Detail: Synchronous Registered (Buffered)
    Speed: 3200 MHz
    Manufacturer: Samsung
    Serial Number: 43F7C4E7
    Asset Tag: CPU0_DIMM_C0_AssetTag
    Part Number: M393A8G40BB4-CWE
    Rank: 2
    Configured Clock Speed: 3200 MHz
    Minimum Voltage: 1.2 V
    Maximum Voltage: 1.2 V
    Configured Voltage: 1.2 V

Handle 0x0049, DMI type 17, 92 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0043
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: Unknown
    Data Width: Unknown
    Size: No Module Installed
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: CPU0_DIMM_C1
    Bank Locator: NODE 1
    Type: Unknown
    Type Detail: Unknown
    Speed: Unknown
    Manufacturer: NO DIMM
    Serial Number: NO DIMM
    Asset Tag: NO DIMM
    Part Number: NO DIMM
    Rank: Unknown
    Configured Clock Speed: Unknown
    Minimum Voltage: Unknown
    Maximum Voltage: Unknown
    Configured Voltage: Unknown

...

Handle 0x0062, DMI type 17, 92 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0043
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 72 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 64 GB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: CPU1_DIMM_H0
    Bank Locator: NODE 7
    Type: DDR4
    Type Detail: Synchronous Registered (Buffered)
    Speed: 3200 MHz
    Manufacturer: Samsung
    Serial Number: 43F7C7CE
    Asset Tag: CPU1_DIMM_H0_AssetTag
    Part Number: M393A8G40BB4-CWE
    Rank: 2
    Configured Clock Speed: 3200 MHz
    Minimum Voltage: 1.2 V
    Maximum Voltage: 1.2 V
    Configured Voltage: 1.2 V

Handle 0x0063, DMI type 17, 92 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0043
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: Unknown
    Data Width: Unknown
    Size: No Module Installed
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: CPU1_DIMM_H1
    Bank Locator: NODE 7
    Type: Unknown
    Type Detail: Unknown
    Speed: Unknown
    Manufacturer: NO DIMM
    Serial Number: NO DIMM
    Asset Tag: NO DIMM
    Part Number: NO DIMM
    Rank: Unknown
    Configured Clock Speed: Unknown
    Minimum Voltage: Unknown
    Maximum Voltage: Unknown
    Configured Voltage: Unknown


The slots A0/A1 B0/B1 are a single channel. The letter denotes the memory channel and the number is the bank within that channel. Every memory channel can have 2 DIMMs connected.
Each processor has 8 channels meaning 16 slots (banks) of memory per processor.
With 2 processors that means 32 total banks of memory.

This machine has a total of 16 memory installed, so it should not be utilizing the 2DPC function at all. I have also checked other 2 * 8352Y machines, and only 16 banks were found.

@Frontier_Setter  Just because you are not using 2DPC doesn't mean it isn't enabled. Other machines may well have it disabled in the firmware. The fact you have channels A0/A1 tells me that this particular system has two dimms per channel enabled, even if not physically available on the motherboard.
